# Image processing and neural networks approach

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network

I am currently working on a project for identification of mood/emotions of a person .
As the first step we are working on a image recognition , detection and tracking python code.
I went through the various different approach towards this problem and found out.

1)Haar cascade method (fast but no scope for recognition and reading expressions ).

2)Neural networks(Great at image recognition ie for details such as smile/ anger..... ).

I am confused with neural networks , ie the approach.

We can first use haar cascade to detect the faces with ease(really fast) then use either canny edge detection or Cropping to crop out the part of the face.
After that is done i have no clue on how to proceed .

This is my idea of it.
continue using haar cascade method to detect the features of the face like eyes, nose ,cheek ,lips....
then find out the distance between them to find out ratios which we can further use to form a neural network .
Different internal layers would be used to detect different features.
We can use differential method to optimize the cost by altering the weights of the synapses .

How good is the approach and is there a better way to do it .

Like say we can use canny edge to detect the edges and then make a new matrix just out of the edges and then use this to train the data.
I dont know , i am really confused.

Anyways thanks in advance for all answers

Comment: nowadays you do not need (nor should) use such an engineering based approach. You can train convolutional neural networks directly on your faces.

Comment: can you brief on convolution neural networks

Answer (score 2):

Image processing libraries such as [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) or [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_table_of_contents_imgproc/py_table_of_contents_imgproc.html#py-table-of-content-imgproc) are a good place to start. For example, [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_canny/py_canny.html#canny)'s an example of canny edge detection in OpenCV.

Regarding neural networks, as [lejlot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2658050/lejlot) pointed out, you've got to ask yourself how much you want to build from scratch.

An example for building your own neural network based on some parameters (which you'd have to define for your facial features), I suggest you read through [A Neural Network in 11 lines of Python](http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/) which illustrates some of problems you might face (especially part 2 where it's about image processing too).

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to need are Convolutional Neurl Networks (check this http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/ to learn about them).

Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN for short) are a kind of neural nets that learn to extract visual features from an image and how to relate those features to recognize what's on the image, so you don't need to detect all the features, just give a CNN a bunch of labeled face pictures and it will learn to identificate the mood of the eprson.

What you can do is to detect the face in every picture (openCV is good enough at detecting faces) and then crop and align each face so all the faces have the same size. Then feed the CNN with all the faces, and it will gradually learn to recognize the emotions of a person.